# Objective C NSUnarchiver null

Tags: objective-c, nskeyedunarchiver

I have the following code (Xcode 8.2, OSX, not iOS):

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:bookmarURL];
NSLog(@"Data: %@",data);

NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
NSLog(@"Unarchiver: %@",unarchiver);
```

The output is:

```
Data: <626f6f6b bc020000 ...(Shortening) ... 04010000 00000000 10d00000 04000000 00000000>
Unarchiver: (null)
```

Data is defined. Why is unarchiver null?

Edit:
I'm running above code inside table delegate method

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
```

viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                  row:(NSInteger)row {

Comment: Call `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]` instead.

Comment: If `Data` exists but `Unarchiver` don't, that means your `Data` isn't a valid archived object.